# Corrupt .8xp file for TI 84+

Tags: compilation, ti-basic, z80

I am trying to write a few programs for my TI 84+ calculator. I am writing in a basic text editor on my desktop and then compiling into `.8xp` files, because it is much easier than typing on the actual device. I would then like to pass the `.8xp` file to my calculator via TI Connect.

However, the programs I write on my desktop do not transfer to the calculator because they are "corrupt or invalid." There are no syntax errors in my TI Basic code, and it runs perfectly on my TI emulator on my computer.

I've written the *exact* same program on my desktop and on my calculator to experiment with the problem, and when I compare the `.8xp` hex files, they are almost identical, but differ slightly. Is this simply because my compiler for my `.8xp` files is not working properly? If that was the case, why would it run in my emulator and not the actual calculator? Are there certain functions that I should avoid when programming in TI Basic on my computer, because the compiler may have a hard time compiling? Does anyone know how to fix these corrupt file issues? I've been perusing Google to no avail as well.

If it helps, `.8xp` files are the user-written program files for the TI-84+, which uses `z80` assembly. I am using the Wabbitemu emulator.

**EDIT:** Here are the two .8xp files that are not the same. One was written on my computer and then compiled, and the other was written on my calculator. The code for the program is:

```
Output(1,1,"HELLO")
```

From my calculator:

```
2a2a 5449 3833 462a 1a0a 0050 726f 6772
616d 2066 696c 6520 3130 2f32 392f 3136
2c20 3130 3a33 3600 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0020 000d 000f 0005 4845 4c4c
4f00 0000 0000 0f00 0d00 e031 2b31 2b2a
4845 4c4c 4f2a 1122 05
```

From my computer:

```
2a2a 5449 3833 462a 1a0a 0047 656e 6572
6174 6564 2062 7920 7468 6520 5449 2d42
4153 4943 2043 6f6d 7069 6c65 722e 0000
0000 0000 0021 000d 0010 0005 4845 4c4c
4f32 0000 0000 1000 0e00 e031 2b31 2b2a
4845 4c4c 4f2a 113f 9605
```

In addition, here's the .8xp for my program that is *allegedly* corrupt or invalid. The code is for the game Checkers (keep in mind it still needs some serious optimization):

```
2a2a 5449 3833 462a 1a0a 0047 656e 6572
6174 6564 2062 7920 7468 6520 5449 2d42
4153 4943 2043 6f6d 7069 6c65 722e 0000
0000 0000 0011 0d0d 0000 0d05 4348 4543
4b45 5253 0000 000d fe0c 2a53 4554 2955
5029 424f 4152 443f e13f 3104 583f d158
6d38 3fe0 582b 392b 2a2d 2a11 3f31 7058
0458 3fd4 3f36 3404 b55d 0011 3fe2 302b
5d00 113f 3104 5d00 1032 113e 3104 5d00
1034 113e 3104 5d00 1036 113e 3104 5d00
1038 113e 3104 5d00 1039 113e 3104 5d00
1031 3111 3e31 045d 0010 3133 113e 3104
5d00 1031 3511 3e31 045d 0010 3138 113e
3104 5d00 1032 3011 3e31 045d 0010 3232
113e 3104 5d00 1032 3411 3f32 045d 0010
3431 113e 3204 5d00 1034 3311 3e32 045d
0010 3435 113e 3204 5d00 1034 3711 3e32
045d 0010 3530 113e 3204 5d00 1035 3211
3e32 045d 0010 3534 113e 3204 5d00 1035
3611 3e32 045d 0010 3537 113e 3204 5d00
1035 3911 3e32 045d 0010 3631 113e 3204
5d00 1036 3311 3f08 3132 2b31 3209 045d
013f 2a44 5241 5729 5049 4543 4553 294f
4e29 424f 4152 443f 2a4f 2a04 aa00 3e2a
702a 04aa 013e 2af0 2a04 aa02 3f31 0458
3e31 0459 3e31 045b 3e30 0441 3fd1 5b6d
3634 3f52 454d 4149 4e44 4552 105b 2b38
1104 583f ce58 6a30 3e38 0458 3f12 105b
8338 1170 3a34 2b30 1104 593f 5d00 105b
1104 413f ce41 6a31 3ee0 592b 582b aa00
113f ce41 6a32 3ee0 592b 582b aa01 113f
5b70 3104 5b3f d43f 2a55 4929 5354 5546
463f e031 2b31 302b 2a54 5552 4e3e 292a
113f e033 2b31 302b 2a53 454c 4543 542a
113e e034 2b31 322b 2a50 4945 4345 2a11
3f2a 4d41 494e 2947 414d 4529 4c4f 4f50
3f2a 1050 2b51 1129 6a29 4355 5253 4f52
2943 4f4f 5244 533f 2a10 412b 4211 296a
2950 5245 5649 4f55 5329 434f 4f52 4453
3f2a 5b29 6a29 4c49 5354 2949 4e44 4558
2941 5429 5052 4556 494f 5553 3f2a 5a29
6a29 4c49 5354 2949 4e44 4558 2941 5429
4355 5253 4f52 3f2a 5229 6a29 5641 4c55
4529 4154 2950 5245 5649 4f55 533f 2a4d
296a 2949 4e54 4552 4d45 4449 4154 4529
5641 5249 4142 4c45 2910 5445 4d50 113f
2a46 2b47 296a 2949 4e54 4552 4d45 4449
4154 4529 5641 5249 4142 4c45 2910 5445
4d50 113f 2a4e 296a 2949 4e54 4552 4d45
4449 4154 4529 4d41 5448 2956 4152 4941
424c 453f 2a10 552b 5611 296a 294d 4f56
4529 434f 4f52 4453 3f2a 4829 6a29 434f
554e 5445 5229 464f 5229 464c 4153 4849
4e47 2943 5552 534f 523f 2a43 296a 29ad
3f2a 5729 6a29 4d4f 5645 294c 1031 113c
5210 3211 3f2a 4429 6a29 4355 5252 454e
5429 504c 4159 4552 2910 4529 6a29 4845
4c50 4552 2956 4152 113f 2a4a 2b4b 296a
2944 4f55 424c 4529 4a55 4d50 2943 4f55
4e54 4552 3f2a 4929 6a29 5354 4154 5553
294f 4629 4741 4d45 3f34 0450 3e31 0451
3e31 0441 3e31 0442 3e30 045b 3e30 045a
3e30 0452 3e31 0444 3e30 0449 3fd1 496a
303f 5004 413e 5104 423f 3882 4104 4e3e
4e71 3804 4e3e 4e70 4204 5b3f d272 3fad
0443 3fd4 3f5d 0010 5b11 0452 3fce 526a
303e e041 2b42 2b2a 292a 113f ce52 6a31
3ee0 412b 422b aa00 113f ce52 6a32 3ee0
412b 422b aa01 113f ce43 6a32 343e 5171
3104 513f ce43 6a32 353e 5071 3104 503f
ce43 6a32 363e 5170 3104 513f ce43 6a33
343e 5070 3104 503f ce43 6a31 3035 3ecf
3e3f 3882 5004 4e3e 4e71 3804 4e3e 4e70
5104 5a3f 3004 483e 3004 573e 3004 4a3e
3004 4b3f 5d00 105a 1104 523f e034 2b31
302b 2a29 2929 2929 2929 2a11 3ee0 342b
3132 2b2a 4d4f 5645 2a11 3fce 526a 3240
446a 313e cf3f d157 6a30 3fce 486b 333e
cf3e e050 2b51 2b2a 292a 113e d03e e050
2b51 2baa 0111 3ed4 3f52 454d 4149 4e44
4552 105a 7139 2b38 1104 553f ce55 6a30
3e38 0455 3f12 1010 5a71 3911 8338 1170
3a34 2b30 1104 563f ce10 5a71 3911 6d30
3c5a 6a35 373c 5a6a 3431 3c5a 6a32 353c
5a6a 393e cf3e b031 0446 3ed0 3e5d 0010
5a71 3911 0446 3ed4 3fce 466a 303e cf3e
e056 2b55 2b2a af2a 113f d03e ce46 6a31
4010 5a71 3138 116c 3040 105a 7139 116f
3537 4010 5a71 3911 6f34 3140 105a 7139
116f 3235 4010 5a71 3911 6f39 3ecf 3e5a
7139 045a 3e52 454d 4149 4e44 4552 105a
7139 2b38 1104 553e ce55 6a30 3e38 0455
3e12 1010 5a71 3911 8338 1170 3a34 2b30
1104 563e 5d00 105a 7139 1104 463e 5a70
3904 5a3e ce46 6a30 3ecf 3ee0 562b 552b
2aaf 2a11 3e31 044a 3ed4 3ed4 3ed4 3f52
454d 4149 4e44 4552 105a 7137 2b38 1104
553f ce55 6a30 3e38 0455 3f12 1010 5a71
3711 8338 1170 3a34 2b30 1104 563f ce10
5a71 3711 6d30 3c5a 6a38 3c5a 6a32 343c
5a6a 3430 3c5a 6a35 363e cf3e b031 0447
3ed0 3e5d 0010 5a71 3711 0447 3ed4 3fce
476a 303e cf3e e056 2b55 2b2a af2a 113f
d03e ce47 6a31 4010 5a71 3134 116c 3040
105a 7137 116f 3840 105a 7137 116f 3234
4010 5a71 3711 6f34 3040 105a 7137 116f
3536 3ecf 3e5a 7137 045a 3e52 454d 4149
4e44 4552 105a 7137 2b38 1104 553e ce55
6a30 3e38 0455 3e12 1010 5a71 3711 8338
1170 3a34 2b30 1104 563e 5d00 105a 7137
1104 473e 5a70 3704 5a3e ce47 6a30 3ecf
3ee0 562b 552b 2aaf 2a11 3e31 044b 3ed4
3ed4 3ed4 3f48 7031 0448 3fce 486e 363e
3004 483f ad04 433f ce43 6a32 343e 3104
573f ce43 6a32 363e 3204 573f ce43 6a31
3035 3ecf 3e33 0457 3e31 0445 3ed0 3e32
0445 3ed4 3fd4 3ed4 3fce 526a 3140 446a
323e cf3f d157 6a30 3fce 486b 333e cf3e
e050 2b51 2b2a 292a 113e d03e e050 2b51
2baa 0011 3ed4 3f52 454d 4149 4e44 4552
105a 7039 2b38 1104 553f ce55 6a30 3e38
0455 3f12 1010 5a70 3911 8338 1170 3a34
2b30 1104 563f ce10 5a70 3911 6e36 353c
5a6a 383c 5a6a 3234 3c5a 6a34 303c 5a6a
3536 3ecf 3eb0 3104 463e d03e 5d00 105a
7039 1104 463e d43f ce46 6a30 3ecf 3ee0
562b 552b 2aaf 2a11 3fd0 3ece 466a 3240
105a 7031 3811 6b36 3540 105a 7039 116f
3840 105a 7039 116f 3234 4010 5a70 3911
6f34 3040 105a 7039 116f 3536 3ecf 3e5a
7039 045a 3e52 454d 4149 4e44 4552 105a
7039 2b38 1104 553e ce55 6a30 3e38 0455
3e12 1010 5a70 3911 8338 1170 3a34 2b30
1104 563e 5d00 105a 7039 1104 463e 5a71
3904 5a3e ce46 6a30 3ecf 3ee0 562b 552b
2aaf 2a11 3e31 044a 3ed4 3ed4 3ed4 3f52
454d 4149 4e44 4552 105a 7037 2b38 1104
553f ce55 6a30 3e38 0455 3f12 1010 5a70
3711 8338 1170 3a34 2b30 1104 563f ce10
5a70 3711 6e36 353c 5a6a 3537 3c5a 6a34
313c 5a6a 3235 3c5a 6a39 3ecf 3eb0 3104
473e d03e 5d00 105a 7037 1104 473e d43f
ce47 6a30 3ecf 3ee0 562b 552b 2aaf 2a11
3fd0 3ece 476a 3240 105a 7031 3411 6b36
3540 105a 7037 116f 3537 4010 5a70 3711
6f34 3140 105a 7037 116f 3235 4010 5a70
3711 6f39 3ecf 3e5a 7037 045a 3e52 454d
4149 4e44 4552 105a 7037 2b38 1104 553e
ce55 6a30 3e38 0455 3e12 1010 5a70 3711
8338 1170 3a34 2b30 1104 563e 5d00 105a
7037 1104 473e 5a71 3704 5a3e ce47 6a30
3ecf 3ee0 562b 552b 2aaf 2a11 3e31 044b
3ed4 3ed4 3ed4 3f48 7031 0448 3fce 486e
363e 3004 483f ad04 433f ce43 6a32 343e
3104 573f ce43 6a32 363e 3204 573f ce43
6a31 3035 3ecf 3e33 0457 3e32 0445 3ed0
3e31 0445 3ed4 3fd4 3ed4 3fe0 332b 3130
2b2a 2929 2929 2929 292a 113f e034 2b31
302b 2a29 2929 2929 2929 2a11 3fe0 362b
3130 2b2a 574f 524b 494e 472a 113f e038
2b31 302b 2a3a 2a11 3fce 446a 313e cf3f
ce57 6a31 4046 6a30 3ecf 3ece 4a6a 303e
cf3e 3204 5d00 105a 7139 113e 3004 5d00
105a 113e d03e ce4a 6a31 3ecf 3e32 045d
0010 5a71 3138 113e 3004 5d00 105a 113e
3004 5d00 105a 7139 113e d43e d43e d43f
ce57 6a32 4047 6a30 3ecf 3ece 4b6a 303e
cf3e 3204 5d00 105a 7137 113e 3004 5d00
105a 113e d03e ce4b 6a31 3ecf 3e32 045d
0010 5a71 3134 113e 3004 5d00 105a 113e
3004 5d00 105a 7137 113e d43e d43e d43f
e038 2b31 312b 2a3a 2a11 3fd0 3e3f ce57
6a32 4046 6a30 3ecf 3ece 4a6a 303e cf3e
3104 5d00 105a 7039 113e 3004 5d00 105a
113e d03e ce4a 6a31 3ecf 3e31 045d 0010
5a70 3138 113e 3004 5d00 105a 113e 3004
5d00 105a 7039 113e d43e d43e d43f ce57
6a31 4047 6a30 3ecf 3ece 4b6a 303e cf3e
3104 5d00 105a 7037 113e 3004 5d00 105a
113e d03e ce4b 6a31 3ecf 3e31 045d 0010
5a70 3134 113e 3004 5d00 105a 113e 3004
5d00 105a 7037 113e d43e d43e d43f e038
2b31 312b 2a3a 2a11 3fd4 3f31 0458 3e31
0459 3e31 044d 3e30 044e 3f08 302b 3009
045d 013f d14d 6d36 343f 5245 4d41 494e
4445 5210 4d2b 3811 0458 3fce 586a 303e
3804 583f 1210 4d83 3811 703a 342b 3011
0459 3f5d 0010 4d11 044e 3fce 4e6a 303e
e059 2b58 2b2a 292a 113f ce4e 6a31 3ecf
3ee0 592b 582b aa00 113e 5d01 1031 1170
3104 5d01 1031 113e d43f ce4e 6a32 3ecf
3ee0 592b 582b aa01 113e 5d01 1032 1170
3104 5d01 1032 113e d43f ce4d 6a31 363e
e038 2b31 322b 2a3a 2a11 3fce 4d6a 3332
3ee0 382b 3133 2b2a 3a2a 113f ce4d 6a34
383e e038 2b31 342b 2a3a 2a11 3fce 4d6a
3633 3ee0 382b 3135 2b2a 3a2a 113f 4d70
3104 4d3f d43f ce5d 0110 3111 6a30 3e32
0449 3fce 5d01 1032 116a 303e 3104 493f
ce45 6a32 3e32 0444 3fce 456a 313e 3104
443f e038 2b31 362b 2a3a 2a11 3fe0 342b
3130 2b2a 2929 2929 2929 292a 113f e031
2b31 302b 2a54 5552 4e3e 292a 113f e033
2b31 302b 2a53 454c 4543 542a 113e e034
2b31 322b 2a50 4945 4345 2a11 3fe0 362b
3130 2b2a 2929 2929 2929 292a 113f d43f
2a55 4929 5354 5546 463f ce44 6a32 3ee0
312b 3136 2baa 0011 3fce 446a 313e e031
2b31 362b aa01 113f ce50 6a30 3e31 0450
3fce 506a 393e 3804 503f ce51 6a30 3e31
0451 3fce 516a 393e 3804 513f e050 2b51
2baa 0211 3fe0 382b 3130 2b2a 2929 2929
2929 292a 113f d43f 6aa5
```

Comment: Although I cannot pinpoint the problem, I can suggest a tool. SourceCoder 3 is an online editor that has been reliable to me. It has great support for TI-BASIC and Axe source. ClrHome.org also has a reliable tool.

Comment: Are you able to link to an example problematic .8xp? It might be easier for a fresh set of eyes to compare and contrast with the file format documentation, e.g. http://merthsoft.com/linkguide/ti83+/fformat.html

Comment: @Tommy Do you mean the TI BASIC text file or the actual compiled .8xp file?

Comment: The compiled file, as it's the tool we're verifying. Possibly even the two .8xps that should be identical but are not?

Comment: @Tommy Please see most recent edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I can see between the two .8xps, both of which appear to have correct headers and checksums, is that the one from your computer, which is a byte longer, appends a `0x3f` 'hard return' after its tokenisation of `Output(1,1,"HELLO")`. The last two bytes are a checksum, the 0x3f when present is the byte before that, and the earlier differences are all about the different length of subsequent data.

So, if I had to go out on a limb, is this perhaps a CR/LF misunderstanding? Maybe you're using a tool originally designed under Linux with text from a Windows-hosted editor? Try eliminating your final line break entirely if you can as a test; if that succeeds then see whether your editor supports using only linefeed characters rather than carriage return + linefeeds.

Comment: That could very well be the problem, but my compiler automatically adds that line in before compilation. Do you know how to get rid of the CR/LF from the `.8xp` file, or is that too difficult to do?

Comment: Ideally you'd get rid of it before, as I think you'd need to parse the thing at the token level, to differentiate hard returns from e.g. a '?' within a string, then there are at least two length counts and a checksum to adjust. Would a pre-filter on your text source to look for all instances of `\r\n` and replace them with `\n` be acceptable? It could create intermediate file(s) if your editor has problems if and when it opens files with a mix of line endings.

Comment: That could very well be the issue, but I feel it will be too much of a hassle to diagnose the compiler when there are other working examples out there. I think I'm going to move to SourceCoder 3 as @Zeda mentioned, because it doesn't cause the issues that my compiler does. Anyways, thanks for the help